# Datos no se muestran en tag <select> dinámico

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo dos tablas en una base de datos:

usuario: rut(pk), nombre, apellido.

vehículo: patente(pk), marca, modelo, rut(fk).

Quiero registrar vehículos mediante el uso del rut (pk) de los usuarios, por lo que pueden tener uno o varios vehículos.

Lo que busco es que salgan los datos de la columna rut en un tag , o sea que las opciones mostradas aumentan conforme se registran más usuarios. Me basé en códigos que vi en videos y foros.

Mi problema es no muestra ningún dato, sólo se queda en "Cargando..." . No he logrado identificar el error.

Método:

```
<script>
      function llenarArray(){
        $('#llenarConDatos').empty();
        $('#llenarConDatos').append("<option>Cargando...</option>");
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "llenarSelect.php",
          contentType: "applicaction/json: charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data){
            $('#llenarConDatos').empty();
            $('#llenarConDatos').append("<option value='0'>--Seleccionar rut--</option>");
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
              $('#llenarConDatos').append('<option value="'+data[i].rut+'">'+data[i].rut+'</option>');
            });
          },
          complete: function(){
          }
        });
      }

      $(document).ready(function(){
        llenarArray();
      });
    </script>
```

Archivo php relacionado a la base de datos:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT rut FROM usuario");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
  $data = array();
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $data[] = array(
      'rut' => $row['rut'];
    );
  }
  header('Content-type: applicaction/json');
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Así se ve la pantalla donde se ingresan los datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes usar funciones `mysqli_*` en lugar de `mysql_*`, te falta la `i`. En el log deberían verse esos mensajes de error.

Answer (score 1):

Peimero, la extension MySQL esta obsoleta desde PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0 en su lugar debes usar MySQLi. Estas usando dos metodos dentro de la extension MySQL: `mysql_num_rows()` y `mysql_fetch_array()` en su lugar usa `mysqli_num_rows()` y `mysqli_fetch_array()` respectivamente.

Segundo, la funcion mysqli_num_rows() devuelve un entero(int) por lo que no deberias usarlo dentro de un if ya que no hay ninguna expresion, es decir, te falta la conficion. En vez de `if(mysql_num_rows($sql))` deberia ser `if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)`.

Tu codigo que daria asi:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT rut FROM usuario");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
  $data = array();
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $data[] = array(
      'rut' => $row['rut'];
    );
  }
 // Observacion: deberias colocar la funcion header() siempre al principio de tu script 
  header('Content-type: applicaction/json');
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```